# Finding baseline predictors given set of ratings in pysark?

Tags: python, apache-spark, dataframe, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I am trying finding baseline predictors given set of ratings in pysark?

as part of this i have created dataframe which look like below.

```
+---------+-----+-----+-----+
|user_code|56691|56693|60762|
+---------+-----+-----+-----+
|   975072|    1|    1| null|
|   975079|    1|    1| null|
|   975076|    2|    1|    2|
+---------+-----+-----+-----+
```

expected output:[calculating bias for each cell of the above matrix]

```
+---------+-----+-----+-----+
|user/item|56691|56693|60762|
+---------+-----+-----+-----+
|   975072|1.083|1.086| null|
|   975079|1.083|1.086| null|
|   975076| 3.15| 3.19|  1.0|
+---------+-----+-----+-----+
```

formula:

```
reg_param1=25,
reg_param2=10
avg=2.0
rows=users who has rated items 
columns=items that have been rated
BI=sum((user who rated item i)-avg)/(reg_param1+(number of users who has rated item i ))
BU=sum((items rated by user u)-avg)/(reg_param2+(number of items rated by item u ))


 for example:user 975072 has rated item 56691 as 1
    for User-975072 item-56691  i.e  user who rated item i is 1 and number of users who has rated item i is 3 users (975072,975079,975076)
    my BI=(1-2.0)+(1-2.0)+(2-2.0)/(25+3)
    and 
    BU=sum((items rated by user u)-avg -BI)/(reg_param2+(number of items rated by item u ))
```

here

```
 (items rated by user u)-avg i.e in this case user user 975072 is rated to 

  item 56691 i.e (1-2.0-BI) and also he rated item 56693 i.e (1-2.0-BI)
    but he is not rated to item 60762 so we no need to conceder so my final calculation like below
    BU=(1-2.0-BI)+(1-2.0-BI)/(10+2)

    my finall bias=avg+BI+BU
    expected 0utput User-975072 item-56691  -1.083
```

my expected output is

```
+---------+-----+-----+-----+
|user/item|56691|56693|60762|
+---------+-----+-----+-----+
|   975072|1.083|1.086| null|
|   975079|1.083|1.086| null|
|   975076| 3.15| 3.19|  1.0|
+---------+-----+-----+-----+
```

how can i iterate through each cell of the dataframe?

Comment: reg_param1=25 ,reg_param2=10

Comment: rows=users who  has rated items

Comment: columns=items that have been rated

Comment: eg:user 975072 has rated item 56691 as 1

Comment: Ramesh,add some more details in question

Comment: add some more details in question

Comment: when you say `BU=(1-2.0-BI)+(1-2.0-BI)/(10+2)` which BI is that? BI are different for different columns. isn't it?